# using facebook graph to insert user into database

Tags: facebook-graph-api, spring-security

Im building a web app where user can register using normal way or through [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.3)

I use the graph api to collect the user data (name,email,etc...) and insert into the table,

my Users table is this (int Id, String Name, String password,etc..)

**but what do i insert as a user password when using facebook graph api,**?? I thought to use [access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending), but they are short lived, even long lived ones can expire

## Update

lets say I leave the password blank, how do I authenticate him without password??

Im using **Spring MVC security**, which needs **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken**

or should i override the scenario when user is from facebook and handle it myself?? but isnt this reinventing the wheel?

Comment: If the user doesn't have a password because they used some other authentication method then you don't have to fill the password column at all - it can be null. In any case, you won't be inspecting that value since you are not handling their authentication - Facebook is.

Answer (score 0):

How i would do this is is by creating another table for my Facebook users and use the id from Facebook as id in your table and then when the user logs in with Facebook you can check if it already exists etc...

Not sure if this is the best way to go but this is how i would probably do it.